# Alter MySQL Key order

Tags: mysql, sql

Think I have a mysql table TBL of these keys

### TBL

- A_KEY
- X_KEY
- B_KEY

Now I want to change this to:

- A_KEY
- B_KEY
- X_KEY

How do you do this?

Comment: This is meaningless.  Post the CREATE TABLE statement including the index definitions.

Comment: I want to do it for increased readability, i know i can drop the table and create it or use select   A_KEY, B_KEY, X_KEY from Tbl

Comment: The order of columns in a table is meaningless just like the (non existing) order of the rows. If you rely on some specific column order you are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN B_KEY int(11) AFTER A_KEY;
```

I used int(11), but you have to use the same type your column B_KEY is now, it won't work without it.

Comment: Doesn't  work for me, `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'B_KEY' in 'mytable'`